# v-if not working for form validation and displaying errors

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to validate a simple form that contains two fields:

- A select box
- A file field

If one of the fields aren't filled in, a div (containing an error label) should be rendered next to the corresponding input field.

The problem: My 'error divs' aren't rendered when pushing data to the errors object (if the form is invalid).
Please note my console.log statement, that tells me that my error object has a key 'file' and a key 'selectedSupplier'.

Side note: I'm following this example: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/form-validation.html
Differences are, that I'd like to show error labels next to the corresponding field and that I'm setting errors in my errors object, instead of a simple array. So what could I be doing wrong?

Thanks.

This is my Main.vue file:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <form @submit="upload">
            <div class="mb-8">
                <h1 class="mb-3 text-90 font-normal text-2xl">Import Order Csv</h1>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="flex border-b border-40">
                        <div class="w-1/5 px-8 py-6">
                            <label for="supplier_id" class="inline-block text-80 pt-2 leading-tight">Supplier</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="py-6 px-8 w-1/2">
                            <select v-model="selectedSupplier" id="supplier_id" name="supplier_id" ref="supplier_id" class="w-full form-control form-input form-input-bordered">
                                <option v-for="supplier in suppliers" v-bind:value="supplier.id">{{ supplier.name }}</option>
                            </select>

                            <div v-if="errors.hasOwnProperty('selectedSupplier')" class="help-text error-text mt-2 text-danger">
                                Required.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="flex border-b border-40">
                        <div class="w-1/5 px-8 py-6">
                            <label for="csv_file" class="inline-block text-80 pt-2 leading-tight">File</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="py-6 px-8 w-1/2">
                            <input id="csv_file" type="file" name="file" ref="file" @change="handleFile">

                            <div v-if="errors.hasOwnProperty('file')" class="help-text error-text mt-2 text-danger">
                                Required.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flex items-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary inline-flex items-center relative">Import</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            this.listSuppliers();
        },
        data() {
            return {
            errors: [],
            file: '',
            suppliers: [],
        };
    },
    methods: {
        checkForm() {
            if (!this.selectedSupplier) {
                this.errors.selectedSupplier = 'Supplier required';
            }

            if (!this.file) {
                this.errors.file = 'File required';
            }
        },
        listSuppliers() {
            const self = this;

            Nova.request()
                .get('/tool/import-order-csv/suppliers')
                .then(function (response) {
                    self.suppliers = response.data.data;
                })
                .catch(function (e) {
                    self.$toasted.show(e, {type: "error"});
                });
        },
        handleFile: function (event) {
            this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
        },
        upload: function (event) {
            this.checkForm();

            if (this.errors.hasOwnProperty('selectedSupplier') || this.errors.hasOwnProperty('file')) {
                console.log(this.errors); // this actually shows both errors!
                event.preventDefault();
            }

            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', this.file);

            formData.append('supplier_id', this.$refs.supplier_id.value);

            const self = this;

            Nova.request()
                .post('/tool/import-order-csv/upload',
                    formData,
                    {
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                        }
                    }
                ).then(function (response) {
                    self.$toasted.show(response.data.message, {type: "success"});
                })
                .catch(function (e) {
                    self.$toasted.show(e.response.data.message, {type: "error"});
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: you are using errors as object, but in data() you pass an empty array as initial value

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This didn't fix it yet though :(

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I had to use v-show instead of v-if, because v-if would be 'lazy' and will not render my error-div when the errors var gets filled.

It's working now, but not 100% sure if this is the best way, as I found another tutorial where v-if is used for form validation.(https://medium.com/@mscherrenberg/laravel-5-6-vue-js-simple-form-submission-using-components-92b6d5fd4434)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, this is how I solved the problem,

```
<div v-if="errors.field1.length > 0 ? true : false"> // true or false
```

If you fix the code like this it will work

Comment: Select your code and press Ctrl + K to format your code

Answer (score 0):

The reason might because the way you reassign object is not reactive, which not trigger v-if to re-calculate

```
this.errors.selectedSupplier = 'Supplier required';
this.errors.file = 'File required';
```

If you still want to use v-if , try change to this approach

```
this.errors = {...this.errors, selectedSupplier: 'Supplier required' }

this.errors = {...this.errors, file: 'File required' }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I handle my errors with VueJS is through lists and their `length` attribute.

I have an `errors` object in my data that looks like this:

```js
errors: {
  field1: [],
  field2: [],
}
```

Then, when I submit the form, I will:

- Empty all the lists for the errors (ie clearing the previous errors)
- `.push()` new errors in the right lists (and `.push()` makes the Vue reactive)

Finally, in my form, my respective errors divs are displayed based on the length of the list:

```html
<div class="error" v-if="errors.field1.length > 0">
    use a v-for to display all the errors from the list
</div>
```

Hope it helps